# How does this code lead to the populating of dummy and the L3 list as well?

Tags: java, linked-list

In this code, I am making use of the concept of dummy nodes. For this, I understand how the dummy list gets populated, however, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how the l3 list gets populated as well. I am just thinking of it as a initializer for the dummy list.

For instance, when the code runs for the first time, considering L1 (1 > 2 > 4) and L2 (1 > 3 > 4). When the dummy.next statement runs, it populates both the dummy and the L3. Why is that?

```
public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode dummy = l3;
        
        while(l1 != null && l2 != null){
            if(l1.val <= l2.val){
                dummy.next = l1;
                l1 = l1.next;
            }
            else{
                dummy.next = l2;
                l2 = l2.next;
            }
            
            dummy = dummy.next;
        }
        
        return l3.next;   
    }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `ListNode dummy = l3;` makes the `dummy` reference of type `List` point to `l3`. Therefore, any changes made to `dummy` change `l3` as well.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that the method mutates nodes `l1` and `l2`. Those changes will be visible on the calling side. This is because `dummy.next = l1` does not create a copy of `l1`, but references `l1`. And when `dummy = dummy.next` is executed, `dummy` now references `l1`.

Comment: If possible, could you expand on that? I cannot seem to wrap my head around how instantiating with l3 ultimately lead to it being updated as well. @JustAnotherDeveloper

Comment: `dummy` and `l3` reference the exact same node, you have two references to one single node.

Comment: @luk2302 and because of that any change made to one is reflected on the other?

Comment: yes, `dummy` and `l3` are referencing the same node, hence change in one will be reflected in the other

Comment: Sure. When you do `ListNode l3 = new ListNode(0)` you're basically saying "l3 now points to a location in RAM where data that represents a ListNode is stored, and I will refer to that location by the name l3". And when you do `ListNode dummy = l3` what you are doing is pointing `dummy`at the same location in RAM, saying "and now I will also refer to that location by the name dummy". Therefore, when you make any changes to `dummy` you are updating the data in the same location in your RAM that `l3` refers to, and therefore also affecting `l3`. Is that more clear?

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper Yes, thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the dummy.next statement runs, it populates both the dummy and the L3. Why is that?

when you are assigning one object to another, you making a link between both of these object's address (dummy and l3 for example). Assume -

You have object A (address 1000); now when you are assigning another object with it, like following :

> A = B

you are actually making a replica of object A, in the name of B (with address 1000). Now both the object pointing to the same location in RAM, whatever changes you will make on one object it will reflect on other as well.

I think you got your answer.

EXTRA:

you have some problem in your code, debug it to make it acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, I did not include the entire code. Just the relevant portions.

Answer (score 0):

Let us work through this one with an example. Say we have two lists as follows:

```
[L1-one | next] --> [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null
[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
```

Where the first "field" reflects some unique identifier for the rest of the discussion and `-->` reflects the `next`-references.

Now the algorithm starts by receiving two lists `l1` and `l2` as parameters:

```
  l1
   |
   v
[L1-one | next] --> [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null
[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
   ^
   |
  l2
```

And it creates a dummy-node for the new list, stores it as `l3` and `dummy`

```
  l3, dummy
   |
   v
[L3-dummy | next] --> null
```

Now depending whether `l1.val < l2.val`, either `l1` or `l2` will be set to `dummy.next`. Let us assume that `l1.val < l2.val`, thus `l1` is set as `dummy.next`:

```
  l3, dummy
   |
   v
[L3-dummy | next] --.
                    |
  l1  .-------------.
   |  |
   v  v
[L1-one | next] --> [L1-two | next] --> [L2-three | next] --> null




[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
   ^
   |
  l2
```

Next, `l1` is set to `l1.next`:

```
  l3, dummy
   |
   v
[L3-dummy | next] --.
                    |
      .-------------. l1
      |                |
      v                v
[L1-one | next] --> [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null




[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
   ^
   |
  l2
```

Finally, in the last step, `dummy` is set to `dummy.next`:

```
  l3
   |
   v
[L3-dummy | next] --.
                    |
dummy .-------------. l1
   |  |                |
   v  v                v
[L1-one | next] --> [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null




[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
   ^
   |
  l2
```

The iteration starts again. Now let us assume that `l1.val > l2.val`. Thus, `dummy.next` is set to `l2`, `l2` is set to `l2.next` and `dummy` is set to `dummy.next`, resulting in the following image:

```
  l3
   |
   v
[L3-dummy | next] --.
                    |
   .----------------. l1
   |                   |
   v                   v
[L1-one | next] --. [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null
                  |
   .--------------.
   |
   v
[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --> null
   ^                   ^
   |                   |
dummy                 l2
```

And for the next iteration, let us assume that `l1.value < l2.value`. We would finish the iteration with the following diagram:

```
  l3
   |
[L3-dummy | next] --.
                    |
   .----------------. l2                  l1
   |                   |                   |
   v                   v                   v
[L1-one | next] --. [L1-two | next] --> [L1-three | next] --> null
                  |    ^
   .--------------.    |
   |                   .--------------.
   v                                  |
[L2-one | next] --> [L2-two | next] --.
                       ^
                       |                     
                    dummy
```

The other iterations will only move `l1`, `l2` and `dummy`, but not change the structure of the objejcts.

Now notice that `l3` is still referencing the initial dummy head and that some references from the first and second list has changed.